# Can I apply for a Dutch passport before 28

Tags: citizenship, dual-citizenship

My grandfather was born in Breda in the 40’s and moved to Australia in the 60’s. He has never naturalised and is still currently a Dutch citizen. My mother was born in Australia in 1970 and by law (I think) was born a Dutch citizen. My mother gave birth to me in Australia in 1992... am I eligible? From the information I could find she lost her citizenship by default at 28 (6 years after I was born), and I believe I have until the end of 2020 to apply before I lose mine at 28. How do I prove that my mother was a Dutch national at the time of my birth when she has never held a certificate of nationality or passport? Thanks

Comment: Does your grandfather have a passport? What documents do you and your mother have eg birth certificate?

Comment: I think you may have lost your Dutch citizenship when your mother turned 28; a minor child normally does under Dutch law. Did she ever live outside Australia between the ages of 18 and 27?  To prove that your mother was a Dutch national you would need her birth certificate, some evidence of her father's Dutch nationality, and possibly her parents' marriage certificate.  Also, if you were Dutch when you were born, you'll lose your Dutch nationality on your 28th birthday, not at the end of the year (unless you were born at the end of the year).